# How many international languages does the iPhone Simulator support?

Tags: iphone, ios, simulator

How many international languages does the iPhone Simulator support?

Choose: Settings/General/International/Language

Mine only has English listed, but I fear I may have inadvertently stripped out the localisations?

[iPhone/Settings/General/International/Language http://i36.tinypic.com/1q50t1.png](http://i36.tinypic.com/1q50t1.png)

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue, mine only has 6 languages showing.

Comment: Nic, you will have to reinstall Xcode/SDK. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reinstalled the SDK/Xcode and got all 40 of them back.

(was 18, but now it's more)

Comment: This may solved your problem but it's not an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Mine support 18 languages. Maybe try to reset content and settings...

Answer (score 0):

Mine is also 18 and in response to your request for a screenshot here it is:
[iPhone Simulator Languages http://img.skitch.com/20081023-1kw7jjymr9sr9dc59eyfqunr5x.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20081023-1kw7jjymr9sr9dc59eyfqunr5x.jpg)

Have you tried resetting the content and settings in the Simulator menu?